# Suppress supplementary error message from unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

I am using [assertRegexpMatches](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRegexpMatches) in my unittests:

`self.assertRegexpMatches(text, regexp, msg='custom short message')`

The problem is that unittest adds it's own error message to the `msg` specified as argument:

`AssertionError: <custom short message>: '<regexp>' not found in '<text>'`

Since the text to match is quite large (~1 page), it messes up the test reports. Is there any way to suppress unittest from adding the `'<regexp>' not found in '<text>'` part to the specified error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84cf25da86e8/Lib/unittest/case.py#l977), it's impossible to suppress the message as long as you use `TestCase.assertRegexpMatches`.

```
def assertRegexpMatches(self, text, expected_regexp, msg=None):
    """Fail the test unless the text matches the regular expression."""
    if isinstance(expected_regexp, basestring):
        expected_regexp = re.compile(expected_regexp)
    if not expected_regexp.search(text):
        msg = msg or "Regexp didn't match"
        msg = '%s: %r not found in %r' % (msg, expected_regexp.pattern, text) #<-
        raise self.failureException(msg)
```

You need to define your own assertion method or use custom string class as follow:

Example (not beautiful solution, but works):

```
import unittest

class CustomString(str):
    # XXX: implementation dependant
    # redefine `__repr__` because `assertRegexpMatches` use `%r`
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Huge string>'

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertRegexpMatches(CustomString('1234'), 'abcd', msg='custom msg')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

---

or using `re.search` with `assertTrue`:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertTrue(re.search(regexp, text), msg='custom msg')
```

Comment: In the code, there is an attribute `self.longMessage` which many other assert functions seem to respect. I wonder why it was decided (was it decided?) that assertRegexpMatches will not respect this attribute.

Comment: Also found documentation for the [longMessage](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.longMessage) attribute.

Comment: @Dhara, I added an workaround. But as you commented, it would be good if `assertRegexpMatches` respect `longMessage` attribute.

Comment: I was running into a similar issue with `assertIn()`, and this was really helpful. But it looks like the default value for `longMessage` is now `True`. (See [cpython source here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/032de7324e30c6b44ef272cea3be205a3d768759/Lib/unittest/case.py#L410).) I ended up setting `self.longMessage = False` only in the individual test functions where I wanted to suppress long `x not found in y` messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the assertRegexpMatches method:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertRegexpMatches(self, text, expected_regexp, msg=None):
        try:
            unittest.TestCase.assertRegexpMatches(self, text, expected_regexp, msg)
        except Exception, e:
            msg = str(e)
            shortened_msg = (msg[:100]+'...' if len(msg)>100 else msg)
            raise self.failureException(shortened_msg)
```

Or if you don't need the message at all:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertRegexpMatches(self, text, expected_regexp, msg=None):
        try:
            unittest.TestCase.assertRegexpMatches(self, text, expected_regexp, msg)
        except Exception, e:
            raise self.failureException(msg or "Regexp didn't match")
```